# 2 div ids need to take up half page each

Tags: html, css

I have 2 div ids in an html document, each with a different background color. I need to have each one take up exactly half of the page. So half the page will be one color, the other half.. will be another color.

Comment: So the question is? And wheres your code to show what you are done so far...

Comment: Have you tried something yourself? Don't expect us to write your code, show us what you have already tried, maybe even some code (albeit broken)

Comment: Set the first answer as marked so people don't waste their time to read the question and try to answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EqVv4/) - half vertical

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EqVv4/1/) - half horizontal

Do this in your css:

```
html,body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}

#div_one{
  height:100%; /*50 for other way */
  width:50%; /*100 for other way */
  background:#f00;
  float:left; /*or display:inline-block; */
}

#div_two{
  height:100%; /*50 for other way */
  width:50%; /*100 for other way */
  background:#00f;
  float:left; /*or display:inline-block;*/
}
```

Then in your html:

```
<div id="div_one"></div>
<div id="div_two"></div>
```

Comment: Everyone has to start from somewhere? @Ruddy

Comment: Half of page i am thinking of it like `height:50% width:100%`

Comment: @laaposto http://jsfiddle.net/EqVv4/1/ <-- Look at that.

Comment: @BeatAlex Yes they do. you giving them the code doesnt teach them. They will take it and put another question asking "How do I put a title on it".. etc. You should just comment to a good site to get them started. This is basic HTML and CSS.

Comment: You can do that if you want then? I'm not stopping you @Ruddy

Comment: may be a stupid question i agree, but this was an interview question i missed

Comment: @BeatAlex I didn't say you were. You doing this just makes other new users think we just write code for anyone asking.

Comment: @BeatAlex: He can do that if he wants, but what's the point if you're just going to encourage bad questions anyway? (I'm more surprised you even managed to come up with an answer that the asker could mark as correct in the first place.)

Comment: I wasn't 'encouraging' as such, I was just answering a question. I learnt from this one, so wont happen again in future @BoltClock

Comment: Fair enough. By answering the questions, though, you're indirectly telling them that it's OK to post poor questions because hey, they still get their answers anyway. That's why people don't really like it when people answer poor questions.

Comment: Yeah I realize that now, sorry. @BoltClock